# The value that I get from <li> doesn't change when the href is changed

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have a ul li in html that is a dropdown.

Index.html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 100%;">
  <li rel="3" class="category"><a class="dropdown-item" href="/index2.html#section2" target="_blank"></a></li>
  <li rel="4" class="category"><a class="dropdown-item" href="/index2.html#section2" target="_blank"></a></li>
  <li rel="5" class="category">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/index2.html#section2" target="_blank"></a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

script.js

```
var val = 1;
$(".category").click(function(){
    val = $(this).attr('rel');
  });
```

In my index.html when I checked the console, the val is already changed to whatever the user clicked, but when it opened the index2.html, the val is back again to 1. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `val` variable isn't persisting throughout reloads and on other pages on the site. This is something that regular old variable just can't do.

A common solution to this is to put state like `val` in [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Properties of `sessionStorage` persist through page reloads and can be accessed on any page of your site. Instead of using traditional variables, you use the [`sessionStorage.setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [`sessionStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) functions.

To use `sessionStorage` with your code, you'd just need to change your JS setting `val` to this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('val', 1);
$(".category").click(function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('val', $(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

Then whenever you need to access the `val` variable you just use this instead:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('val')
```

Comment: May it is better to use sessionStorage in this scenario

Comment: @CristóbalDíazÁlvarez Possibly, but either will work. OP doesn't say how long the persistence should last, so `localStorage` is never a bad guess.

Comment: If the user open another tab, the data of the links would be in an unexpected behaviour, in the case of user clicking links en different tabs. Should be sessionStorage to avoid that